# Unbind and bind dynamically on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I´ve been reading here, but I could not find a good solution yet.
I need to unbind an element to avoid a user trigger that event more than one, until finish, and I want to do it generic for all my onClick events.

I have multiple pages with onClick event, so I just want that adding this "openDialog" class in the elements, I can get this new event and then disable all the others onClick events of the elements.

```
    var currentElement;

    var events;

    var initializeDialogEvent = function () {
    $(".openDialog").on("click", function () {
        currentElement = $(this);
        events = $._data(currentElement.get(0), "events");
        debugger;
        $.each(events, function(i, event) {
            $.each(event, function(j, h) {
                debugger;
                if(h !== undefined){
                    currentElement.unbind("click", h.handler);
                }
            });
        });


        //$(events).each(function( index ) {
        //    debugger;
        //    currentElement.unbind($(this));
        //});
        //$(this).off();
    });
```

All those onClick events are opening a dialog, so I have a callback funtion that is call when the dialog is open, and there, is when I want put it back the onClick event

```
    $(document).on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(events).each(function( i, event ) {
            $.each(event, function(j, h) {
                if(h !== undefined){
                    currentElement.bind("click",h.handler);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

So far I achieve to unbind the events, but I cannot put it back.
Any idea what I´m doing wrong?.

Regards.

Comment: may be you can use this:- http://jsfiddle.net/39mfrf6m/10/

Comment: I clarify a little bit better the ticket. This event that I paste it´s shared and used for multiple elements, and what I want to do there it´s disable the other events that the element has and the put it back when the dialog it´s open